# Botón flotante circular - Creación

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy empezando a trabajar con los botones flotantes (Fab) y me gustaría resolver una duda.

A la hora de implementarlos no tengo problemas, pero si que me gustaría cambiar la disposición de los botones al pulsar el botón principal.

Adjunto una imagen para explicarme mejor:

- Esto es lo que he codificado hasta ahora:

  - Java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello, he seguido el siguiente código

```
 public void creacion_fab() {
    fab_rankit = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_rankit);
    fab_buscar = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_buscar);
    fab_cambioActividad = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_cambioActividad);
    fab_home = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_home);

    FabOpen = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
    FabClose = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_close);
    FabClockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_anticlockwise);
    FabAnticlockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotate_clockwise);

    fab_rankit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isOpen) {
                fab_home.startAnimation(FabClose);
                fab_cambioActividad.startAnimation(FabClose);
                fab_buscar.startAnimation(FabClose);
                fab_rankit.startAnimation(FabClockwise);
                fab_home.setClickable(false);
                fab_buscar.setClickable(false);
                fab_cambioActividad.setClickable(false);
                isOpen = false;

            } else {
                fab_home.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                fab_cambioActividad.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                fab_buscar.startAnimation(FabOpen);
                fab_rankit.startAnimation(FabAnticlockwise);
                fab_home.setClickable(true);
                fab_buscar.setClickable(true);
                fab_cambioActividad.setClickable(true);
                isOpen = true;
            }
        }
    }); } }
```

- XML

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/id_principalActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="mario.rankit.Principal_Activity">


<include layout="@layout/content_principal_" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:backgroundTint="#0089D5"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:src="@drawable/home"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/fab_buscar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"

    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_buscar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:backgroundTint="#0089D5"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:src="@drawable/fab_buscar"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/fab_cambioActividad"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"

    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_cambioActividad"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:backgroundTint="#0089D5"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:src="@drawable/fab_publicar"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/fab_rankit"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_rankit"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="74dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:backgroundTint="#0089D5"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:src="@drawable/logofinal"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"

    />


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorToolbar"
        android:title="@string/titulo_principal"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buscar" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bt_alertas"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/alertas" />
```

Sin embargo, lo que estoy buscando es la siguiente disposición de botones:
(lo que adjunto no es sino tan sólo una imagen diseñada a través de Paint. No esta codificado)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguno sabe como implementarla? 
Gracias

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que deseabas lograr, solo agregar botones? En la segunda imagen aparenta que quieres mostrar los botones en forma de satelite.

Comment: Sí, quería crear un Botón flotante circular. Antes no sabía como se llamaba pero ahora sí, y por eso he editado la pregunta. Así se queda como fuente de información

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente he resuelto mi problema.
He implementado el botón flotante de la siguiente manera:

Código Java:

```
   public void creacion_fab(){
        ImageView icon = new ImageView(this);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.logofinal);

        FloatingActionButton fab_rankit;
        fab_rankit = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_rankit);

        SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(130,130);
        itemBuilder.setLayoutParams(params);

        ImageView fab_home = new ImageView(this);
        fab_home.setImageResource(R.mipmap.fab_home);

        ImageView fab_buscar = new ImageView(this);
        fab_buscar.setImageResource(R.mipmap.fab_buscar);

        ImageView fab_publicar = new ImageView(this);
        fab_publicar.setImageResource(R.mipmap.fab_publicar);



        SubActionButton button1 = itemBuilder.setContentView(fab_publicar).build();
        SubActionButton button2 = itemBuilder.setContentView(fab_buscar).build();
        SubActionButton button3 = itemBuilder.setContentView(fab_home).build();

        //attach the sub buttons to the main button
        FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(this)
                .addSubActionView(button1)
                .addSubActionView(button2)
                .addSubActionView(button3)
                .attachTo(fab_rankit)
                .build();
    }
```

Este es el resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que a alguien le sea últil

Comment: Veo que FloatingActionButton es una librería, aunque no veo un ejemplo de como realizar la distribución en un arco de los botones, https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton suena interesante si en verdad se puede realizar esto.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el comentario. Ya resolví el cómo hacerlo. He publicado el código necesario